# How can I prevent Chrome from preloading HTML5 audio and video contents?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, html5

I like HTML5 and its features a lot. But the one thing irritates me is that I can't control the actual downloading of contents.

Every time I see an HTML5 audio file, say, in a RSS feed, Chrome will start to download it automatically! This is especially annoying when I don't have intention to listen to any of the  files that are preloading. I want to listen to very few of them.

Is there any way to tell Chrome to not waste my bandwidth on files that I don't intend to listen/watch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't *currently* seem to be a way to tell Chrome not to download resources until you explicitly request them (I even checked in their [Extensions Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore?category=ext) to see if someone wrote an extension that could do this).

The Opera Developer's guide for HTML5, *[Everything you need to know about HTML5 video and audio](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)* states:

> **What's up with all that downloading?**
>
> Opera, Chrome and Safari will
>   automatically download the whole video
>   file even if it  hasn't started to
>   play yet. Firefox 3.6 only loads
>   enough to render a frame and determine
>   duration, unless the `autobuffer`
>   attribute is present. Note that the
>   spec changed from `autobuffer` to
>   `preload`, which hasn't been implemented
>   anywhere yet. Opera plans to change to
>   the Firefox behavior of only loading
>   enough to render a frame and determine
>   duration by default, unless the
>   `preload` attribute says otherwise.

It was a known issue that Chrome ignores the `preload` attribute, which means it's always preloading the video, even if it's not supposed to. The good news, though, is that [this bug has been fixed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16482#c72) in the latest developer version of Chrome:

> Comment 72 by project member vrk@chromium.org, Apr 5 (6 days ago)
>
> The patches to implement preload have now landed! The preload attribute will be finally recognized in Chrome 12. (Dev channel should get this update in a few weeks.)

Once this change takes place (depends on what version of Chrome you're using), you should see the audio files not preloading unless the RSS feed, webpage, etc, explicitly states that it should preload.

My understanding of HTML5 leads me to believe that if the web designer has it set to preload, there's nothing that you can do to tell it not to. My guess, though, is that we'll soon see an extension or option in browsers that will allow you to choose whether a source preloads or not (I would think kind of like how [Chrome's Click to Play for plugins](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/13/google-chrome-gets-click-to-play/) works).

Comment: HTML5 is not a standard. It's not even a draft, just some stuff said to be a new "standard". Every dev, company, browser implements it in an other way.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension to do this. Disable Autoplay Reloaded.

It stops both autoplay and preload.

It does datamine your domains you browse that it activates on though.

But even with the extension, chrome will *still preload the metadata* to show how long the audio or video file is.

This cannot (yet) be stopped.

This is to stop people from downloading audio and video files protected by one time tokens.  if you could prevent the preload, then you could right click the audio player and download without a token expired message.

Comment: Your last para is wrong, the server will send the file if it receives the token, then set the token as expired. Changes on the client will not change the requirement to get a token before downloading. This can't be a reason to deny preload controls. Did you notice this is from 2011.

Comment: You are wrong. :)

When chrome preloads the metadata, it keeps the connection open, so you can still press play later and still have it play using the same token.   but trying to download will not work.  If preloading the metadata was actually prevented, then the token would not expire until you pressed play, or picked download.

I have tested this TODAY.

Comment: Can you provide an example. That server is not working correctly.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-html5-autoplay-re/  this is the extension that tries to do this. most people say it works.